# Simple C++ program exceeds its array boundaries and crashes

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I am a C++ newbie. I want to generate a random sequence of strings to be used in my program. It works most of the time, but occasionally it misbehaves and dumps a random string from the computer memory. What silly mistake(if any) have I made?

The code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> // Needed for the true randomization
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string holder[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    int xRan;
    srand(time(0)); // This will ensure a really randomized number by help of time.

    xRan=rand()%6+1;
    xRan--;
    cout << "Value of xRan is: " << xRan << " value is " << holder[xRan] << endl;   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's going out of bounds, last index of your array is 4

Comment: 66% of the time it works every time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xRan calculation gives you a number from 1 to 6.  Your array has 5 elements, and they are numbered 0 to 4.

Change `xRan=rand() % 6 + 1;` to `xRan=rand() % 5;`, then get rid of the next line where you decrement `xRan`.  This will give you a number from 0 to 4, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
xRan=rand()%6+1;
xRan--;
```

Will generate a random number from 0 to 5. Your valid array indices are 0 through 4.

Comment: He decrements `xRan` on the next line, so the index is 0..5 (although this is still goes out of bounds of course).

Comment: @PaulR Thanks. That's what I get for trying to answer on 2 hours of sleep, I suppose.

Comment: I notice the same effect when I try to answer SO questions before the first cup of coffee of the day!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough elements in `holder` (you need 6). Change:

```
string holder[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
```

to:

```
string holder[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
```

Note also that you have some redundancy here:

```
xRan=rand()%6+1;   // xRan = 1..6
xRan--;            // xRan = 0..5
```

You could change this to just:

```
xRan=rand()%6;     // xRan = 0..5
```

Comment: No he'll need more than 6 I believe. Try 7.

Comment: @PaulG: No - he decrements `xRan` after initialising it, so it is initially 1..6, then it becomes 0..5.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't see that part. My apologies.